# NameError: global name 'sourceText' is not defined + python list comparison

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nameerror

Hello and thanks for having a look at my question, I know it has been asked before but for the life of me I can't seem to relate other people's answers to my code.

I also apologise if my question is basic but I'm not that strong a programmer.

This piece of code is supposed to take in two files at a time, that contain text that has been indexed and put into a list (In another bit of code that works).

The first bit of code cycles through all the files in each directory (3) assigning them to sourceText and suspectText.

The code is then supposed to match each of the given lists from the files to show whether or not either list has any similarities. (This has been accomplished in a very basic way using difflib, but I would prefer to know exactly which parts of the lists that are being compared have been copied, so if anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate them).

The main issue with this code though, is that it keeps bringing up the error: 
NameError: global name 'sourceText' is not defined or NameError: name 'sourceText' is not defined, depending on my changes, and it's driving me mad because I can't understand why.

The code has been pasted below and is as is, except for the directory location which has been changed. I am currently using Python 2.7, as I am not fully accustomed to 3 yet.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, so thanks in advance!

(Edited code below)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import string
import pickle
import sys
import glob
import errno
import difflib


sourcePath = 'C:\Users\Sou/*.out'
suspectPath = 'C:\Users\Susp/*.out'
list_of_source_files = glob.glob(sourcePath)
list_of_suspect_files = glob.glob(suspectPath)


def get_source_files(list_of_source_files):

    for source_file in list_of_source_files:
        print source_file
        for source_file_name in list_of_source_files:
            with open(source_file_name) as source_file:
                sourceText = pickle.load(source_file)
            return sourceText

def get_suspect_files(list_of_suspect_files):

    for suspect_file in list_of_suspect_files:
        print suspect_file
        for suspect_file_name in list_of_suspect_files:              
            with open(suspect_file_name) as suspect_file:
                suspectText = pickle.load(suspect_file)
           return suspectText

def matching(sourceText,susText):
    for item in list_of_suspect_files:
        for item in list_of_suspect_files:
            matching = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,susText, sourceText)
            print matching.ratio()

def main(sourceText, suspectText):

    get_source_files(sourceText)
    get_suspect_files(suspectText)
    matching(sourceText,suspectText)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(list_of_source_files, list_of_suspect_files) #these files are the ones I'm not too sure about
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is actually what is going on - you haven't defined `sourceText` (or `suspectText`, for that matter) in your `main()` function.

Try working out a method after your initial variable definitions up top to iterate through the files, and assign each one at a time to these variables. You have `list_of_source_files` and `list_of_suspect_files`, but you don't actually do anything with them. In order to use them in a function (like you're trying to do in `get_source_files()`, you need to pass them to the function as an argument.

For example, if you want to use `sourceText` and `suspectText` in your `main()` function, use this form:

```
def main(sourceText, suspectText):
    # call other functions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(list_of_source_files, list_of_suspect_files)
```

You also need to modify your other functions, as you're doing things like:

```
def get_source_files(sourcePath):
```

but then you never use `sourcePath` in the function.

Comment: Thank you MAttDMo!

How do I pass them to the function, I thought my adding the variable names in the brackets that was what I was doing?

Comment: Bearing in mind I'm not very good at this, isn't there an issue with the files I'm passing into the main function?

In my code above I'm putting list_of_source_files and list_of_suspect_files, shouldn't it be sourceText and suspectText going in there so the text within them can then be compared? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Don't really know, what you want to do. The code is far from working, so I can only guess:

```
import difflib
import glob
import pickle

sourcePath = 'C:\Users\--suspecttext/*.out'
suspectPath = 'C:\Users\--sourcetext/*.out'

def iter_source_files(sourcePath):
    for file_name in glob.iglob(sourcePath):
        with open(file_name) as source_file:
            yield pickle.load(source_file)

def iter_suspect_files(suspectPath):
    for file_name2 in glob.glob(suspectPath):              
        with open(file_name2) as suspect_file:
            yield pickle.load(suspect_file)

def matching(sourceText,suspectText):
    matching = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,sourceText,suspectText).ratio()
    print matching

def main():
    sources = list(iter_source_files(sourcePath))
    for suspect in iter_suspect_files(suspectPath):
        for source in sources:
            matching(source,suspect)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: nice job throwing up a wall of code without a bit of explanation, completely refactoring the OP's code...

Comment: The code was a little confusing as I'm not very good, but thank you commenting regardless Daniel :)